# Constructors and properties being set to private or public

Tags: c#

I am creating a class in C# and am being told that all of my properties should be public. I was taught that information hiding is common in C++ but idk if it is the same is C# or if the convention for doing so is different. The first example is how I was taught to do it. The 2nd example is how I am being taught to implement this class now.
My question is this: Will this prevent me from using any of the properties with other classes or will it all work because of the constructor making them public?

Thank you all in advance

```
    class Book
    {
        string Title = null;
        string Author = null;
        int Year = 0;
        string CoverType = null;

        public Book (string aTitle, string anAuthor, int aYear, string aCoverType)
        {
            Title = aTitle;
            Author = anAuthor;
            Year = aYear;
            CoverType = aCoverType;
        }
```

Separation of examples

```
    
    public class Book
    {
        public string Title = null;
        public string Author = null;
        public int Year = 0;
        public string CoverType = null;

        public Book (string aTitle, string anAuthor, int aYear, string aCoverType)
        {
            Title = aTitle;
            Author = anAuthor;
            Year = aYear;
            CoverType = aCoverType;
        }
```

Comment: In general, no, fields/attributes should not be public. You can add `{ get; set; }` to make publicly mutable/accessible fields

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a field and a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property)

Answer (score 2):

> Will this prevent me from using any of the properties with other classes

No. That's the definition of having `public` modifier.

However, as written in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) public fields are "Generally not recommended"

The common approach is to expose [properties with backing fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties#properties-with-backing-fields).

Answer (score 0):

You should separate *properties* and *fields*, i.e.

```
private int year = 0; // field
public int Year { get { return year;}} // Property, wrapping the field
public int Year2  => year; // Same as above, using more compact syntax
public String Author {get;} // auto-property, automatically adds a hidden field
```

The typical rule is to keep fields private, and if you need public access, wrap them in a property, or use an auto property. So it usually does not make much sense to make properties private, since the goal is usually to expose the underlying field.

I would also recommend using readonly properties whenever practical, i.e. `{get;}` or `{get; init;}`. If the property can never change, there is usually less problems with making it public.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using *properties* instead of *fields*:

- Let's set `Title`, ..., `CoverType` *once* in the consructor and prevent them form occasinal (erroneous) modifications
- Let's validate input arguments, let's not use `null` as placeholder.

**Code:**

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title     { get; }
    public string Author    { get; }
    public int Year         { get; }
    public string CoverType { get; }

    public Book (string aTitle, string anAuthor, int aYear, string aCoverType)
    {
        Title = aTitle?.Trim() 
          ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(aTitle));
        
        Author = anAuthor?.Trim() 
          ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(anAuthor));
        
        Year = aYear > 1400 && aYear <= DateTime.Now.Year + 1
          ? aYear
          : new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(aYear)); 

        CoverType = aCoverType ?? "";
    }

    ...
```